# Как задать background ячейки TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Внезапно обнаружилось что в свойствах нельзя просто задать border для TableLayout. Нашел обход в виде установки на background cell_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
    <solid android:color="#0fff"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

Хочу создать стиль чтобы по умолчанию для любой ячейки применялся указанный background, но не могу найти как. Установка фона для элементов внутри ячеек не пойдет т.к. некоторые из них будут раскрашиваться в разные цвета.
Как решить проблему?

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите чтоб у вас была и рамка и возможность заполнить рамку любым цветом?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да. Но я рассчитывал что рамка это будет свойство таблицы, а цвет свойство текста в ней.

Comment: А почему бы не назначить рамку фоном TableRow, а во внутренних виджетах использовать другой фон?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб TableRow задает фон для целой строки, а мне нужно для каждой ячейки. Чтобы получилась обычная таблица

Comment: Ну... Можно так: у TableRow монолитный фон и padding в 1dp. - У внутренних элементов - непрозрачный фон. Так будет и иллюзия наличия рамки и возможность любой фон поставить ячейке

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Т.е. к отдельно ячейке обратится нельзя?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду можно ли одним каким-то свойством задать рамку - то нет, нельзя.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы программно можно было ставить цвет бордера?